# Detecting thick line clusters and measuring gradient

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, gradient, cluster-analysis

My first post here =)
Im stuck with a seemingly simple computation problem in MATLAB.
I have a 1000x1000 matrix of 0s and 1s. The 1s are clustered in a thick lines diagonally across the matrix and I need to measure the gradient of these line clusters. (The thick white lines that runs SW to NE). 
What i did so far was placing a ruler on each cluster and extracting the points of the lines. This however isnt a solution as i have 2000 matrices to analyze.

[image]

Reading the gradients -

[image]

Problems:

- I cant fit a gradient as there are more than one line cluster.
- I tried using imclose to remove the stray points but it doesnt help me
  isolate each clusters
- I tried using edge detection and Hough
  transforms but neither of them helps me isolates the clusters.

Thanks so much in advance. Do let me know if my problem isnt clear =)

Comment: Hey. I would have but i wasnt allowed to do so. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpmdq8vz0zfjuon/control.jpg
If you dont mind, an example of the matrix is in this link.

Comment: Edited your question. So I am still not clear on `gradient of line clusters`. Ok is it the slope of these clusters?

Comment: Thanks. You are awesome. Regarding the gradient, i would take a ruler and place it as a best fit line to one of the thick white cluster in the picture. From there i would draw a line, and get the gradient of this line. I have edit the picture i uploaded on dropbox, if you click on the above link again you will see what i mean

Comment: So, referring to the newest uploaded picture, do you want gradients for each cluster in the image or like one gradient value that would be like the mean of all the cluster gradients? So, for the uploaded image, do you want four gradient values or just one mean value of the gradients?

Comment: The mean value will do if i can get a certain estimate of the error. But getting all 4 gradients will be the best.

Comment: Also, can I tell the codes to detect first four biggest clusters only? Or do you think some images could have more than 4 clusters that are to be used for gradients calculation? So basically I am wondering if we can set a fixed number as the number of clusters across all of your 2000 matrices that will use the same code?

Comment: Hough transform *should* work...

Comment: Divakar: Thanks for the solution. Ill go through them. And yes to your qn, just the four largest cluster will do.

Comment: Anony-Mousse: I may have understood Hough Transform. But ill go through it again is all else fails. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Select approach
%%//   1. Gradient values for all clusters
%%//   2. One dominant gradient value for one image
approach_id = 1;

%%// Threshold to the number of pixels that a blob must have
%%// to be declared as a cluster
thresh = 850;

%%// Image scaling factor
img_scale = 0.2; %%// 0.2 seemed to work for the sample

img = imread(image_filenpath);
bw1 = im2bw(img,0.3); %%// 0.3 as threshold-level worked for sample image
bw2 = medfilt2(bw1,[5 5]); %%// 5x5 as denoising window worked

[L, num] = bwlabel(bw2, 8);
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));


switch approach_id

    case 1
        count1 = 1;
        for k = 1:num
            if counts(k)>thresh
                bw5 = imresize(L==k,img_scale);
                gradient1(count1) = gradval(bw5);
                count1 = count1+1;
            end
        end

    case 2
        bw4 = false(size(bw1));
        for k = 1:num
            if counts(k)>thresh
                bw4 = bw4 | L==k;
            end
        end
        %%// At this point we have a cleaned-up binary image of the input
        bw5 = imresize(bw4,img_scale);
        gradient1 = gradval(bw5);

end

%%// gradient1 is what you need
```

**Associated function**

```
function gradient_value = gradval(BW)

angles = 45:-1:0;

for iter = 1:numel(angles)
    BWr = imrotate(BW,angles(iter));
    t1(iter) = max(sum(BWr,1));
end
[~,ind] = max(t1);
gradient_value = tand(90 - angles(ind));

return;
```

**Output with cluster gradient values for sample image**

```
gradient1 =

    1.6643    1.9626    2.0503    2.0503
```

Please note that the clusters are ordered according to the column-major indexing as used in MATLAB.